# modem.oqpsk with half sine wave

Tags: encoding, matlab, transmission, modulation

hi i was using the following

```
h = modem.oqpskmod;
```

but it constructs it with default settings, i wanted to model zigbee one which is oqpsk with half sine waves... how could i do it? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this

```
 h = modem.oqpskmod('M',4,'SymbolOrder','Gray','InputType','Bit');
 Data = randint(10000,1);
 output = modulate(h,Data);
 plot(output, 'DisplayName', 'output', 'YDataSource', 'output'); figure(gcf)
```

You can see that the output is and compare it with the graph in [there.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-shift_keying#Offset_QPSK_.28OQPSK.29)

Comment: hi HH, does it mean by default the it will be using "half-sine wave", can you show me the argument which makes it use the "half-sine wave"? thanks!